# No se actualiza el estado del ModalBttonSheet Flutter

Tags: flutter

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema. Cuando se abre el `ModalBottonSheet` y pulso sobre el `CheckBoxListTile`, el estado en el `ModalBottonSheet` no se actualiza, pero internamente la variable se actualiza porque cierro el `ModalBottonSheet` y lo vuelvo a abrir, el estado esta cambiado. Supongo que al hacer el `setState` el `ModalBottonSheet` no se reconstruye

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class CheckboxFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckboxFormField({
    super.key, 
    required this.label,
    required this.icon, 
    required this.keyboardType,
    this.initialText,
    this.readOnly = false,
  });

  final String label;
  final IconData icon;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final String? initialText;
  final bool readOnly;

  @override
  State<CheckboxFormField> createState() => _CheckboxFormFieldState();
}

class _CheckboxFormFieldState extends State<CheckboxFormField> {
  bool valueC = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            onTap: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 0,
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Text('Seleccione un equipo', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFFDA24D), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),),
                          CheckboxListTile(
                            value: valueC, 
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                valueC = value!;
                              });
                            }, 
                            title: Text('title')
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ).then((value) => setState((){}));
            },
            keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
            readOnly: widget.readOnly,
            controller: widget.initialText != null
            ? TextEditingController(text: widget.initialText)
            : null,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            cursorColor: Colors.white,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: widget.label,
              labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)
              ),
              focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)
              ),
              prefixIcon: Icon(widget.icon, color: Colors.white,)
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Y si quiero que se pase como parámetro a la función?

```
CheckboxFormField(
  label: 'Equipos', 
  icon: LucideIcons.users, 
  keyboardType: TextInputType.name, 
  readOnly: true,
  valueC: valueC,
  onChanged: (value){
    setState(() {
      valueC = value!;
    });
  },
),
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class CheckboxFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckboxFormField({
    super.key, 
    required this.label,
    required this.icon, 
    required this.keyboardType,
    required this.onChanged,
    required this.valueC,
    this.initialText,
    this.readOnly = false,
  });

  final String label;
  final IconData icon;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final String? initialText;
  final bool readOnly;
  final bool valueC;
  final Function(bool?)? onChanged;

  @override
  State<CheckboxFormField> createState() => _CheckboxFormFieldState();
}

class _CheckboxFormFieldState extends State<CheckboxFormField> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        onTap: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (context, setState) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Text('Seleccione un equipo', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFFDA24D), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),),
                          CheckboxListTile(
                            value: widget.valueC, 
                            onChanged: widget.onChanged,
                            title: Text('title')
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          );
        },
        keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
        readOnly: widget.readOnly,
        controller: widget.initialText != null
        ? TextEditingController(text: widget.initialText)
        : null,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        cursorColor: Colors.white,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: widget.label,
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)
          ),
          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)
          ),
          prefixIcon: Icon(widget.icon, color: Colors.white,)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Espero que me solucionen el problema. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar `statefulBuilder` dentro del modal, esto te permitirá actualizar el estado de la variable y verás el cambio en la interfaz de usuario:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  elevation: 0,
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (builder,state){
      return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Seleccione un equipo',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFFFDA24D),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20),
              ),
              CheckboxListTile(
                  value: valueC,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    state(() {
                      valueC = value!;
                    });
                  },
                  title: Text('title'))
            ],
          )),
    );
    })
```

Recuerda también cambiar el `setState` por `state` que es la propiedad que te da el `statefulBuilder`

Comment: Y si quiero pasar como parametros `valueC` y `onChanged`. De esta manera no funciona.
```CheckboxFormField(
                      label: 'Equipos', 
                      icon: LucideIcons.users, 
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name, 
                      readOnly: true,
                      valueC: valueC,
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState(() {
                          valueC = value!;
                        });
                      },
                    ),```

Comment: Recuerda también cambiar el setState por state que es la propiedad que te da el statefulBuilder

Comment: He editado la pregunta ya que utilizando lo que me has proporcionado no funciona

Comment: Podría responderme a la nueva sugerencia?